# intersection of geodesiques 

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed riemannian surface . let $\alpha$ be a simple closed geodesique . does  there is exist a simple closed geodesic $\beta$ that intersect alpha at only 1 point p such that $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ does not commute in $\pi_1(M,p)$

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a surface with a Riemannian metric? Otherwise for a Riemann surface, presumably you mean a unique constant curvature metric with curvature $1,0$ or $-1$? 

Comment: You put about 10 spelling errors in 3 lines of text, I corrected them all. Please be more precise next time, we are mathematicians after all, and this is a professional forum. 

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that you corrected all the spelling errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider the punctured torus, then the $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ curves together generate the fundamental group (which is the free group on two generators), and so don't commute. Now, if you have a *closed* riemann surface, one of its handles is a punctured torus, so the above construction goes through without change.

**EDIT** The above answer is for hyperbolic surfaces. Obviously, if the fundamental group is abelian (as for the torus or the sphere or the projective plane), the answer is no.

Comment: i had hyperbolic surfaces in mind when i wrote the question 

Answer (score 5):

No, this is false for any curve $\alpha$ on $M$ a torus, sphere, or projective plane (choosing any Riemannian metric on the surface). For a general surface with a Riemannian metric, you might have a simple closed $\mathbb{Z}/2$-homologically trivial geodesic ($\alpha$ bounds a subsurface), in which case there is no geodesic $\beta$ meeting it in a single point.

If the curve $\alpha$ is non-separating, then this will be true (if $\chi(M)<0$). There exists transverse curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $|\alpha\cap \beta|=1$ and $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ not commuting in $\pi_1(M)$ (with the natural base point).  Then minimal length representatives of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will intersect transversely in a single point (see e.g. a paper of [Hass-Scott](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1259513) for an elementary proof).